# Синтаксическая ошибка php. Обьясните что здесь не так

Tags: php

ругается
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in V:\home\mamdani1.lol\www\index.php on line 72

Подскажите пожалуйста что тут не так

[image]

Comment: Во-первых, код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. Во-вторых, код, показанный вами на этой картинке, ни на что не ругается, синтаксических ошибок здесь нет.

Comment: @andreymal __есть__, если это php5.3 и ранее.

Comment: @u_mulder ну может быть, только вот автор всё равно не указал версию и я проверял в 5.6

Comment: Действительно у меня версия php5.3
Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий синтаксис для записи массивов `[1,2,3]` появился в php5.4. В более ранних версиях используйте запись вида `array(1,2,3)`.